# Making the width Blackberry CheckboxField just enough to fit the text

Tags: java, blackberry, checkbox, width

I have a horizontal field manager with a CheckboxFields in it. My problem is that I need to adjust the width of the checkbox fields manually (i.e. in a static way) which makes the checbox field always a fixed size even when the text is very short.

Is there a way to adjust the width dynamically according to the length of the text for checkbox fields (or in general) ?

EDIT: Actually there is no problem when I run the same code with JDE 7 but when I try with JDE 6 everything becomes very big and the checkbox field label texts become very large pushing my loading icon very far and also making it big. A picture is shown below:

[image]

Comment: What is your layout like? [[label][checkbox]] or [[checkbox][label]]?

Comment: @MisterSmith [[checkbox][label]]

Comment: I don't understand your question then. If the text is left-aligned, it shouldn't matter how long it is.

Comment: Ok, try calling `setFont` on the fields (yes, it works for checkboxes and loading fields also).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I understand what you are asking. Try this one:

```
public class LoadingScreen extends MainScreen
{
public LoadingScreen()
{       
    createGUI();                               
}

private void createGUI()
{
    add(new LabelField("CheckboxField Demo"));


    HorizontalFieldManager HFM1 = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER);

    CheckboxField checkBoxField3 = new CheckboxField("Option 1", false, Field.FIELD_VCENTER)
    {
        protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) 
        {               
            super.drawFocus(graphics, false);
        } 

        protected void layout(int width, int height) 
        {
            super.layout(150, height);
        }

    };

    checkBoxField3.setMargin(0, 10, 0, 0);
    HFM1.add(checkBoxField3);

    CheckboxField checkBoxField4 = new CheckboxField("Option 2", false,  Field.FIELD_VCENTER)
    {
        protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) 
        {               
            super.drawFocus(graphics, false);
        }
        protected void layout(int width, int height) 
        {
            super.layout(150, height);
        }
    };
    HFM1.add(checkBoxField4);

    HFM1.setMargin(10,0,0,0);
    add(HFM1);              
}
}
```

let me know.

Comment: I think this will work but is it possible to do it without using extra labels for the text of checkbox field ?

Comment: @Cemre I edited the code, check it once. If runs well then I think you understand which method is importent over here. :)

Comment: This works but when I try it with different simulators since its not dynamic I still get the same problem I guess I will change the way I use this screen :)